# Create Automate Task on Windows 10 with download and search in PDF

Tags: pdf, scheduled-tasks, notifications, task-scheduler, file-search

I want to create an Automate Task to hourly download a PDF from a specific URL and then search for certain text like "6256896" and then if there was the text inside the PDF,notifies me for example with an email.

Is it possible to do this without programming? and If yes How?

Comment: Only if you have a tool that can perform a search automatically. Downloading from a fixed URL can be accomplished with any number of tools, but I don't know of a good one to search a PDF with a simple command. Does it have to be PDF? This would be much easier with text/HTML.

Comment: @CBHacking I don't provide the PDF file and I don't have another Option.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I don't know of a tool that can easily search a PDF and return a simple result code (the way `findstr` or `grep` can). Maybe somebody else does.

Comment: @CBHacking There is software but it's so expensive;

http://www.powergrep.com/

Comment: Pdfgrep is a tool to search text in PDF files. It works similar to grep. A windows version can be found at http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/pdfgrep-windows-version. It costs 10$.